# xaml parse exception issue only on win7

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-7, inner-exception

I have an issue where I got error

> id 1000 (KERNELBASE.dll)

and

> error id 1026  System.IO.FileNotFoundException

When I try to run my program on **Win 7** (witch had run fine before), but it runs perfectly on win 8/8.1/10. I am running **.Net Framework 4.5**.

I had been trying to deleting the code, but then the error just appears on other lines off my code and thats keeps going on, so does anyone know how to fix it or know how to find out what actually are causing that issue

```
Binding Failure occurred
Message : Managed Debugging Assistant ' Binding Failure ' has detected a problem in ' F: \ Omini \ Omini Dækberegner.exe ' .
Additional information : the assembly with the display name ' PresentationFramework.Aero2 ' could not be loaded into the binding context '
```

C#

```
        InitializeComponent();
        bredebox_nu.Focus();
        textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { bredebox_nu, profilbox_nu, Fælgestr_nu, bredebox_ny, profilbox_ny, Fælgestr_ny, oprofilbox, obredebox, oFælgestr };
        win.SourceInitialized += new EventHandler(win_SourceInitialized);
        List<biler> items = new List<biler>();
```

the other error

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
HResult=-2146233087
Line Number = 616
Line Position = 48
Message = ' There were triggered an exception at setting the property ' System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style ' . ' Line number ' 616 ' and line position ' 48' .
Source = Presentation Framework
Stack Trace :
   by System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load ( XamlReader xamlReader , IXamlObjectWriterFactory writer factory , Boolean skipJournaledProperties , Object rootObject , XamlObjectWriterSettings settings , Uri baseUri )
   by System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml ( XamlReader xamlReader , Boolean skipJournaledProperties , Object rootObject , XamlAccessLevel access level , Uri baseUri )
   by System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml ( Stream stream , ParserContext parserContext , Object parent , Boolean close stream)
   by System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   by Omini_Tires_And_rims.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() i C:\Users\Sindakewin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\omini_dækberegner\omini_dækberegner\MainWindow.xaml:linje 1
   by Omini_Tires_And_rims.MainWindow..ctor() i C:\Users\Sindakewin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\omini_dækberegner\omini_dækberegner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:linje 210
   InnerException: 
   FileName=PresentationFramework.Aero2, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

FusionLog ==== state information prior binding ===
LOG: Display Name = PresentationFramework.Aero2, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35
(Partial)
WRN: There was delivered about a partial binding for assembly:
WRN: Assemblyname: PresentationFramework.Aero2, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35 | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial binding Occurs tabloid is only given part of assemblyens display name.
WRN This may cause the binder inputting a wrong assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to give up fully specified text ID for the Assembly,
WRN: consisting of the simple name, version, culture and token for the public key.
WRN: For more information and common solutions to this problem in the white paper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270.
LOG: Appbase = file: /// F: / Omini /
LOG: First PrivatePath = NULL
```

## Calling assembly: Presentation Framework, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35.

```
LOG: This binding initiates in loadingcontex default.
LOG: User application configuration file: F: \ Omini \ Omini Dækberegner.exe.Config
LOG: User host configuration file:
LOG: User machineconfigurationsfile from C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ config \ machine.config.
LOG: Policy not applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assemblybinding).
LOG: Attempting to download new URL file: /// F: /Omini/PresentationFramework.Aero2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting to download new URL file: /// F: /Omini/PresentationFramework.Aero2/PresentationFramework.Aero2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting to download new URL file: /// F: /Omini/PresentationFramework.Aero2.EXE.
LOG: Attempting to download new URL file: /// F: /Omini/PresentationFramework.Aero2/PresentationFramework.Aero2.EXE.
)
 HRESULT = -2147024894
   Message = The file or the assembly ' PresentationFramework.Aero2 , PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35 ' or one of its dependencies could not be loaded . The specified file was not found.
   Source = mscorlib
   StackTrace:
   by System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad (AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly location hint, Stack Crawl Mark & ​​stack field, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
        by System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad (AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly location hint, Stack Crawl Mark & ​​stack field, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
        by System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName (AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, Stack Crawl Mark & ​​stack field, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
        by System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (AssemblyName assemblyRef)
        by System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveAssembly (BamlAssembly bamlAssembly)
        by System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlTypeToType (BamlType bamlType)
        by System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType (BamlType bamlType, int16 typeid)
        by System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType (int16 typeid)
        by System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_ElementStart ()
        by System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_OneBamlRecord ()
        by System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.ReadObject (KeyRecord record)
        by System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.CreateObject (KeyRecord key)
        by System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValue (Object key, Object & value, Boolean & canCache)
        by System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.OnGettingValuePrivate (Object key, Object & value, Boolean & canCache)
        by System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock (Object key, Boolean & canCache)
        by System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue (Object key, Boolean & canCache)
        by System.Windows.DeferredResourceReference.GetValue (Base Value Source Internal value source)
        by System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.get_NewValue ()
        by System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnTemplateChanged (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        by System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged (DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        by System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged (DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        by System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        by System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
        by System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyStyleOrTemplateValue(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp)
        by System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject container, FrugalStructList`1& exclusionContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1& newContainerDependents)
        by System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle)
        by System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style& styleCache)
        by System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        by System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        by System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        by System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        by System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
        by System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
        by System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
        by MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
        by MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
   InnerException:
```

Xaml `<GridViewColumn Header="Model" Width="140" >
       <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Model}" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" />
       </DataTemplate>
       </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       </GridViewColumn>`

Comment: your screen image presents different type of error.

Comment: yes thats becuase thoose errors i get in my log i think are relating to that error

Comment: what `InnerException` says? Always see `InnerException` cause it gives an actual error.

Comment: Go to "View Detail" and look at the innerexception. And its innerexception. a.s.o. Post those details in english preferably..

Comment: updatet with innerexception i marked all exceptions and i also got a binding failure

Comment: Please post code (c# and xaml) and where and which exception occurs (matching the code).

Comment: updatet but the exceptions occurs in the whole code so i had postet where the exceptions starts at

Comment: i also looked at PresentationFramework.Aero2 witch it says is not found i was trying to look in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF and it seems like PresentationFramework.Aero2 is missing in win7 so is it something that only are being used in win win 8 and above? or can you get it for win7 also?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the .Net Framework? Or repair it? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/04/19/introducing-the-microsoft-net-framework-repair-tool-version-1-3/

Comment: yeah but that didn't solved it i had looked at 5 computers that runs win 7 and none of them have  PresentationFramework.Aero2  only  PresentationFramework.Aero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i removed `PresentationFramework.Aero2` from the references in visual studio and replaced it with `PresentationFramework.Aero` and deleted some of the themes and replaced the namespaces and now it runs fine on win 7 and win vista without any issues